# Battery icon won't update quickly when I start charging

Tags: icons, laptop, battery, taskbar, charging

When I plug in the charger and my laptop starts charging, the battery icon won't update to a **charging battery icon** until after a few minutes.

How can I fix it and make it change immediately?

My laptop : Acer aspire e5-57551nj

Comment: Please look underneath your laptop for the serial number plate. On there will also be a model number, which tells us a lot more about your hardware, Please click [edit] and put the make and model number in your question. Please do not use Add Comment; please use [edit] instead.

Comment: It's normal for power settings to only update every few minutes. It's in the interest of having your system operate as fast as reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's normal for power settings to only update every few minutes. It's in the interest of having your system operate as fast as reasonable" 
WinEunuuchs2Unix